# Objective-C class properties unreachable by Swift subclass

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've created an objective-C Class called `Swipable_TableViewcontroller`, that has two mutable dictionaries `trailingActions` and `leadingActions`, declared as follows:

The `.m` file:

```
#import "Swipable_TableViewController.h"

@interface Swipable_TableViewController ()
@end

@implementation Swipable_TableViewController
NSMutableDictionary *leadingActions;
NSMutableDictionary *trailingActions;

[.........]

@end
```

The `.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Swipable_TableViewController : UITableViewController
@end
```

Plus the bridging header:

```
#import "Swipable_TableViewController.h"
```

Then, I created a Swift class called `Modal_TableViewController` that conforms to `Swipable_TableViewController`.

The problem is that when I try calling the dictionaries from the Swift class, I cannot find them, they're unreachable.
I've never used Obj-C before, but there is no workaround for what I'm trying to do.

How can I be able to add values to the dictionary from within the swift subclass?

Comment: You have to put the declarations of the dictionaries as properties in the header file. These are the same as public properties in a Swift class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
NSMutableDictionary *leadingActions;
NSMutableDictionary *trailingActions;
```

declare them inside .h as

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *leadingActions;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *trailingActions;
```

[image]